# Javascript string formatting, short question

Tags: javascript

How can I use javascript to add a number (any number between 0-100) followed by a underscore, before the variable value?

Example:

```
 2000 becomes 12_2000   //a number of my choice is added followed by an underscore
 hello becomes 12_hello
```

The number (12 in this case) is a constant chosen by me!

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`i + '_' + x` where `i` is the number and `x` is an arbitrary value.

Answer (score 2):

Just use string concatenation:

```
var res = '12_' + myNum;
```

Or with a variable prefix:

```
var res = prefix + '_' + myNum;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just basic string concatenation, which can be done with the + operator:

```
var num = 2000;
"12_" + num;
// "12_2000"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var_name = "2000";
output = "12_" + var_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function prefixWithNumber(value, number) {
  return number + "_" + value;
}
```

This expression is evaluated as `(number + "_") + value`. Since one of the operants in the first addition is a string literal, the second argument `number` is converted (coerced) to a string. The result is a string, which causes the third argument to be converted to a string as well.

This is what the JS engine does behind the scenes:

```
(number.toString() + "_") + value.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're looking for something like this:

```
Object.prototype.addPrefix = function(pre){
    return pre + '_' + this;
  };
```

This allows code like:

```
var a = 5;
alert(a.addPrefix(7));
```

or even:

```
"a string".addPrefix(7);
```

Answer (score 0):

Joining an array can be faster in some cases and more interesting to program than "+"

```
[i, '_', myNum].join('')
```